# Angularfire2 filter data using child exists

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have my data like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF4QI.png).When I need to get data from question list I need to check if the current userid (loggedin user)  exists in **answeredStudents**.If exists then that question need to hide from the user. Otherwise question will be shown in the list.

Here how i get questions:

```
getQuizesSeries()
  {
    let ref = this.afDB.list('questions').snapshotChanges()
    .map(changes =>{
      console.log(changes);
      return changes.map(c=> ({key:c.payload.key,...c.payload.val()}));
    });

    return ref;

  }
```

In my `constructor` I called that `function` like this:

```
  questions:Observable<any[]>;
  quizes:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public afDb:AngularFireDatabase ,public navParams: NavParams,public dataProvider:DataProvider) {
    this.quizes = this.dataProvider.getQuizesSeries();       
  }
```

and here is my `html` where its shows data:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let quiz of quizes |async;let i = index;" >
    <ion-item (click)="passkey(quiz.key)">
        <p>{{quiz.name}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Amarnath If the current logged in uid is exists in answeredstudents it needs to hide from the list.How can i do that?

Comment: where is your passkey function? in your question

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to grab the UID of the current student logged in.

e.g.

```
stduentID = //the id of the logged in user here
```

Then when you are creating the questions in the ion-list, you will have an ngIf
checking the answeredStudents uid with the loggedIn user uid

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let quiz of quizes |async;let i = index;" >
    <ion-item (click)="passkey(quiz.key)" *ngIf="your logic here">
        <p>{{quiz.name}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: actully i know i can have a ngIf and get the data.I also need to know how to pass the logic to here

Comment: you can gave the logic stored in a function, that returns a true or false then in your ngIf will have something lik *ngIf="Yourfunction()", so if the function returns a true, the question will hide

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add a simple example with dummy data to solve this task.
You need to use `filter` operator to filter out the questions that are already answered by the logged user.

In the below code I am checking whether the logged in user has already answered this question or not. If `YES` then skip this question else add this question to question list.

```
let questions = [
  {id: 1, desc: "desc1"},
  {id: 2, desc: "desc2"},
  {id: 3, desc: "desc3"}
];

let answeredStudents = [
  {id: 1, answered: [1]},
  {id: 2, answered: [1, 2]}
];

let loggedUserId = 1;

let questionsObs = Rx.Observable.from(questions);

function hasNotAnswered(id, question) {
  let user;
  answeredStudents.forEach(student => {
    if (student.id === id) {
      user = student;
    }
  });
  return !(user.answered.indexOf(question.id) > -1);
}

questionsObs.filter(question => hasNotAnswered(loggedUserId, question))
  .map(question => questionList.push(question));
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need.But since I'm using firebase its difficult to get questions id(keys) .

Comment: I don't think you necessary need to create another list of questions, you can use ngIf to skip the questions you don't want to show depending on the result of your hasNotAnswered() function. that way you avoid unnecessary arrays

Comment: @LVW23 post the json structure how it looks when you retrive the id which in this keys they are they $key in firebase and make them proporties of the object by doing something like :

 `data.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
      this.questions= [];
      item.forEach(element => {
        var y = element.payload.toJSON();
        y["$key"] = element.key;
        this.questions.push(y as any);
      });`

Comment: @PatricioVargas Either ways .. filtering them before rendering on DOM or filtering them while processing response.

Comment: @LVW23 It might be time consuming as I am not aware of Firebase. So tried with a simple example. You can try this approach and let me know the problem so that we will try to solve it.